# How would a BEC respond to the gravitional force of a small mass so sensitively?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, gravity, laser, bose-einstein-condensate

Recently I watched a BBC programme on anti-gravity, most of which was wishful thinking by NASA and BAe Systems 20 years ago.

At the end of the program through,  they did show what appeared to be a BEC (or liquid Helium, unfortunately I can't remember.

The important point is that the substance in the apparatus did seem to respond quickly to the mass of the two men standing near the apparatus, "flowing" towards them.

I wonder is this possible, i.e. did I really observe a portion of the liquid responding in a significant and easily observable way, to a mass due to gravitational force, and if so, how is this achieved?

If you are based in Britain, or have a VPN program, you can watch the segment (the last 10 minutes) at [Project Greenglow](http://www.bbc.co.uk/iplayer/episode/b0752f85/horizon-20152016-2-project-greenglow-the-quest-for-gravity-control)

My sincere apologies if I have this badly wrong, misinterpreted the effect, or simply need a new set of glasses.